# how to make copy paste to follow the same pattern

Tags: pyqt5

I am creating a design with my `QGraphicsitems` . I have selected all the items in the scene and pasted it.But it is not following the same pattern.can we make the items paste in the same pattern like the one which we have created initially? –

I have tried with the following code

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import (QByteArray,QDataStream, QIODevice,pyqtSlot, QMimeData, QPointF, QPoint, Qt, QRect,QTimer,QLineF, QEvent,QRectF)
  from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor,QDrag, QPainter, QPixmap,QFont,QFontMetrics,QBrush, QLinearGradient, QIcon, QPen, QPainterPath, QTransform,QCursor,QMouseEvent,QClipboard
  from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QGraphicsTextItem,QGraphicsItemGroup, QSizePolicy,QShortcut, QScrollArea, QPushButton,QLineEdit, QMainWindow,QInputDialog, QGraphicsPathItem,QDialog, QVBoxLayout,QGraphicsItem,QStatusBar,QTextEdit, QAction,QMenu, qApp,QSplitter, QButtonGroup, QToolButton, QFrame, QHBoxLayout, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsItem, QGraphicsPixmapItem, QLabel, QGraphicsScene, QWidget
  import importlib
  import SketchBook as sketchBook
  import Blocks as blocks


  import random
  custom_mimeType = "application/x-qgraphicsitems"
  pos1 = QPointF()



  def item_to_ds(it, ds):
      if not isinstance(it, QGraphicsItem):
          return
      ds.writeQString(it.__class__.__module__)
      ds.writeQString(it.__class__.__name__)
      ds.writeInt(it.flags())
      ds << it.pos()

      posdiff = it.pos().x() -pos1().x()
      pos1 = QPointF(it.pos().x(),it.pos().y())
      # ds.writeInt(it.UserType)
      ds.writeFloat(it.opacity())
      ds.writeFloat(it.rotation())
      ds.writeFloat(it.scale())
      # ds.writeString(it.type())
      # ds.writeQString(it.type1())
      # if isinstance(it, QGraphicsItem):
      #     ds << it.brush() << it.pen()
      if isinstance(it, QGraphicsPixmapItem):
          ds << it.pixmap()
      if isinstance(it, QGraphicsPathItem):
          ds << it.path()

  def ds_to_item(ds):
      module_name = ds.readQString()
      class_name = ds.readQString()
      if class_name == 'QGraphicsPixmapItem':
          mod = importlib.import_module(module_name)
          it = getattr(mod, class_name)()
          # flags = QGraphicsItem.GraphicsItemFlag(ds.readInt())
          # pos = QPointF()
          # ds >> pos
          # it.setFlags(flags)
          # it.setPos(pos)
          # it.setOpacity(ds.readFloat())
          # it.setRotation(ds.readFloat())
          # it.setScale(ds.readFloat())
      else:
          mod = importlib.import_module(module_name)
          it = getattr(mod, class_name)(blocks.selectedObjType)
      flags = QGraphicsItem.GraphicsItemFlag(ds.readInt())
      pos = QPointF()
      ds >> pos
      it.setFlags(flags)
      it.setPos(pos)
      it.setOpacity(ds.readFloat())
      it.setRotation(ds.readFloat())
      it.setScale(ds.readFloat())
      # if isinstance(it, QGraphicsItem):
      #     pen, brush = QPen(), QBrush()
      #     ds >> brush
      #     ds >> pen
      #     it.setPen(pen)
      #     it.setBrush(brush)
      if isinstance(it, QGraphicsPathItem):
          path = QPainterPath()
          ds >> path
          it.setPath(path)
      if isinstance(it, QGraphicsPixmapItem):
          pixmap = QPixmap()
          # pen, brush = QPen(), QBrush()
          # ds >> brush
          # ds >> pen
          ds >> pixmap
          it.setPixmap(pixmap)

      return it
  class GraphicsSceneClass(QGraphicsScene):
      global selectedObjType
      def __init__(self, parent=None):
          super(GraphicsSceneClass, self).__init__(parent)
          self.gridOn = 0
          self.setSceneRect(0, 0, 1920, 1080)
          self.setItemIndexMethod(QGraphicsScene.NoIndex)
          self.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(Qt.black))

      def mousePressEvent(self, event):
              sampleTransform = QTransform()
              objectAtMouse = self.itemAt(event.scenePos(), sampleTransform)

              if objectAtMouse and event.button()== Qt.LeftButton:
                  objectAtMouse.setSelected(True)

              elif objectAtMouse==None and event.button()==Qt.RightButton:
                  # pass
                  self.grid = self.TargPosForLine(event.scenePos(), "ForLine")
              self.grid = self.TargPosForLine(event.scenePos(), "ForLine")
              print(self.grid)

              # else:
              #     self.DeselectItems()

              # objectAtMouse.QShortcut
      def TargPosForLine(self, position, mode):

          clicked_column = int((position.y() // 16)) * 16
          clicked_row = int((position.x() // 16)) * 16
          if clicked_column < 0:
              clicked_column = 0
          if clicked_row < 0:
              clicked_row = 0
          if(mode == "ForRect"):
              return QRect(clicked_row, clicked_column,16,16)
          elif(mode == "ForLine"):
              return QPointF(clicked_row,clicked_column)
      def DeselectItems(self):
          selectedObjects = self.selectedItems()
          for object in selectedObjects:
              object.setSelected(False)
      def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
          # self.DeselectItems()
          pass
  class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
      global selectedObjType
      # global item
      def __init__(self,):
          super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
          self.createActions()
          self.createMenus()
          self.createToolbars()

          self.scene = GraphicsSceneClass()
          MainWindow.obj = self.scene
          self.view = QGraphicsView(self.scene)
          # self.view.setDragMode(QGraphicsView.RubberBandDrag)
          self.view.setMouseTracking(True)
          self.view.setRenderHint(QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing)
          self.widg = QWidget()
          self.horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout()
          self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.view)
          self.widg.setMouseTracking(True)
          self.widget = QWidget()
          self.widget.setLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
          self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
          self.obj=None
      def createMenus(self):
          menuBar = self.menuBar()
          fileMenu = menuBar.addMenu('&File')
          fileMenu.addAction(self.exitAction)

          fileMenu = menuBar.addMenu('&Edit')
          fileMenu.addAction(self.copyAction)
          fileMenu.addAction(self.pasteAction)
          fileMenu.addAction(self.selectAction)
      def createActions(self):

          self.exitAction = QAction("E&xit", self, shortcut="Ctrl+X", statusTip="Quit Scenediagram example",
                                    triggered=self.deleteItem)
          self.copyAction = QAction("C&opy", self, shortcut="Ctrl+C", triggered=self.copy)

          self.pasteAction = QAction("P&aste", self, shortcut="Ctrl+V", triggered=self.paste)

          self.selectAction = QAction("S&electAll", self, shortcut="Ctrl+A", triggered=self.selectAll)

      def createToolbars(self):
          GridButton = QToolButton()
          GridButton.setCheckable(True)
          GridButton.setIcon(QIcon('images/GridButton.png'))
          GridButton.clicked.connect(self.GridOnOffControl)
          GridButton.setToolTip("Grid Control")
          self.pointerToolbar = self.addToolBar("Pointer type")
          self.pointerToolbar.addWidget(GridButton)

      def deleteItem(self):
          for item in self.scene.selectedItems():
              self.scene.removeItem(item)
      def selectAll(self):

          for item in self.scene.items():
              item.setSelected(True)

      def GridOnOffControl(self):
          if self.scene.gridOn == 0:
              self.scene.gridOn = 1
          else:
              self.scene.gridOn = 0
          if self.scene.gridOn == 1:
              self.scene.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(QPixmap('images/Grid.png')))
          else:
              self.scene.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(Qt.black))

      def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
          contextMenu = QMenu(self)

          Cutaction = contextMenu.addAction("Cut")
          Coaction = contextMenu.addAction("Copy")
          Paaction = contextMenu.addAction("Paste")
          Propaction = contextMenu.addAction("draw1")
          Propaction1=contextMenu.addAction("draw2")
          quitAct = contextMenu.addAction("quit")
          action = contextMenu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(event.pos()))
          if action == quitAct:
              self.close()

          elif action == Propaction:
              objectDrop = None
              # painterPath = QPainterPath()
              #
              # painterPath.moveTo(10, 50.0)
              # painterPath.lineTo(50,50)
              # painterPath.lineTo(50,55)
              # painterPath.lineTo(10,55)
              # gradient = QLinearGradient(1, 1, 1, 5)
              # gradient.setColorAt(0, QColor(Qt.gray))
              # gradient.setColorAt(0.5, QColor(192, 192, 192, 255))
              # gradient.setColorAt(1, QColor(Qt.darkGray))
              # painterPath.closeSubpath()
              #
              # objectDrop = QGraphicsPathItem()
              # objectDrop.setPath(painterPath)
              # objectDrop.setBrush(QBrush(gradient))
              objectDrop = QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap("2AS_HG_RG.png"))
              objectDrop.setPos(self.scene.grid)
              print("sig",self.scene.grid)
              # objectDrop._position = QPointF(gridPos.x() + 2, gridPos.y() + 5.9)
              # objectDrop._type = "2AS_HG_RG"
              objectDrop._type1 = "2AS_HG_RG"
              self.scene.addItem(objectDrop)
              objectDrop.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
              objectDrop.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
              objectDrop._type1="2AS_HG_RG"
              # self.scene.addPath(painterPath)

          elif action==Propaction1:
              objectDrop = None
              selectedObjType = "line"

              objectDrop = sketchBook.SketchBook(selectedObjType)


              print("line",self.scene.grid)
              objectDrop.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
              objectDrop.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
              objectDrop._type1 = "line"
              objectDrop.setPos(self.scene.grid.x(),self.scene.grid.y()-48+5)
              self.scene.addItem(objectDrop)
          elif action == Coaction:
              self.copy()
          elif action == Paaction:
              self.paste()

      @pyqtSlot()
      def copy(self):

          mimedata = QMimeData()
          ba = QByteArray()
          ds = QDataStream(ba, QIODevice.WriteOnly)
          for it in self.scene.selectedItems():
              self.posdiff=item_to_ds(it, ds)
          mimedata.setData(custom_mimeType, ba)
          clipboard = QApplication.clipboard()
          clipboard.setMimeData(mimedata)

      @pyqtSlot()
      def paste(self):

          pos2=self.scene.grid
          clipboard = QApplication.clipboard()
          mimedata = clipboard.mimeData()
          if mimedata.hasFormat(custom_mimeType):
              ba = mimedata.data(custom_mimeType)
              # STR = str(ba)
              # QW = ba.capacity()
              ds = QDataStream(ba)
              while not ds.atEnd():
              # for it in ds:
                  it = ds_to_item(ds)


                  if isinstance(it, QGraphicsPixmapItem):
                      self.scene.addItem(it)
                      it.setPos(pos2)
                      it._position = QPointF(pos2.x() + 2, pos2.y() + 5.9)
                      print("sig",it._position)
                      it._type1 = "2AS_HG_RG"
                  else:
                      gradient = QLinearGradient(1, 1, 1, 5)
                      gradient.setColorAt(0, QColor(Qt.gray))
                      gradient.setColorAt(0.5, QColor(192, 192, 192, 255))
                      gradient.setColorAt(1, QColor(Qt.darkGray))
                      self.scene.addItem(it)
                      it.setBrush(QBrush(gradient))
                      it.setPos(pos2.x()+self.posdiff().x(),pos2.y()-48)
                      it._position = QPointF(pos2.x() + 2, pos2.y() + 5.9)
                      print(it._position)


                      # it.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)

                      # it._type1 = "line"


      def selectedItem(self):
          items = self.scene.selectedItems()

          if len(items) == 1:
              return items[0]
          return None
  if __name__=="__main__":
      import sys
      app=QApplication(sys.argv)
      mainWindow = MainWindow()

      mainWindow.show()

      sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

1) select all the items or the items to be pasted

2) copy it

3) paste it

if we have design pattern have item1 followed by item2 followed by item3 with respective distance. When we copy and paste it it should follow the same pattern.

Comment: Please, provide a minimal and complete example. We should be able to copy/paste your code and run it

Comment: In `paste()`, you set the position of all items to the same coordinates `pos2`. To get the same relative position of the copied items you need to set the position of each item to something like `it.setPos(it.pos() + pos2)`.

Comment: As @Heike suggests, you'll need to "*add*" the position to the item's existing position, and it should also be relative to a reference point. I've added an answer that should clarify it. PS: I have to agree with Romha: your example has very bad indentation, contains a lot of useless code and also refers to custom modules we don't know anything of. Spend more time and efforts to create straight-to-the-point examples, avoid simple copy/paste: it took me more time to edit your code (which can be written in less than 100 lines) to make it work in the first place, than to find and write a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QGraphicsItem.setPos()` is absolute to the scene (or relative to its parent), the alternative solution is to use `moveBy(x, y)` (which is the same as `setPos(self.pos() + deltaPos)`, but you have to take into account the relative position of the click according to the reference point.

I'd suggest you to *not* set the position until all items have been added, and then set their position according to a specific item that will be used as an "anchor" point.

```py
    @pyqtSlot()
    def paste(self):
        pos2=self.scene.grid
        clipboard = QApplication.clipboard()
        mimedata = clipboard.mimeData()
        items = []
        topLeft = None
        if mimedata.hasFormat(custom_mimeType):
            ba = mimedata.data(custom_mimeType)
            ds = QDataStream(ba)
            while not ds.atEnd():
                it = ds_to_item(ds)
                items.append(it)
                if not topLeft:
                    topLeft = it
                elif it.y() < topLeft.y() or it.x() < topLeft.x():
                    # find a possible topmost/leftmost item
                    topLeft = it
            # add items, but do not set their position here
            # ...

        delta = self.scene.grid - topLeft.pos()
        [i.moveBy(delta.x(), delta.y()) for i in items]
```

An alternative is to find the "anchor" in the copy procedure, and set the position of each item relative to that point in the datastream, so that you'll be able to use `moveBy(pos2.x(), pos2.y())` directly after adding the items.